# SCombinator - Combined Questions of All the sites that API supported

Tags: app, python

### About

Just another combination of all the sites that API supported.

If you use all those sites, it would be very useful, because you can surf all at one place.

Almost real-time like Stack Overflow itself, and VERY fast!

#### License

Will be one of open-sourced license, not decided yet at the moment.

#### Download

Download not Available yet

#### Platform

Any Platform that can run

- Python 2.x (probably 2.5+)
- mysql-python

### Contact

S.Mark

### Code

Not Yet Ready!

### Demo

http://stackinfo.com/scombinator/

Just give it a try, it is *VERY* fast! :-)

Comment: **Note** : I am developing it in same place, so demo site may break frequently. ;)

Comment: I was going to start building an aggregator today if nobody else had done one already. Congrats, it's offline atm but I can't wait to use it.

Comment: @Farseeker, offline because of API is offline? or mine just broken? I have a problem with urllib2 which does not timeout and wait until the server response, and page does not get refresh until it is recovered. Thinking for workaround at the moment.

Comment: @S.Mark don't stress, it was offline for a few minutes 9 hours ago. It works fine now.

Comment: Looks good so far. Will you be adding the ability to choose which sites get aggregated in? In the future when there will be lots of StackExchange sites, this could be really useful.

Comment: @Edan Maor, yeah, I was also thinking to do user selectable but having trouble with performace issue, so currently finding/thinking for good way.

Answer (score 1):

Very cool. Perhaps add the ability to sort and group by application?